# How to Convert Duration to Time on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have duration data in text format like so:

> 19min 30s

I would like to convert this to hours and I need the hours to be integers. How do i do that?
I have tried to split the text but I am unable to categorise the array into hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=("0:"&textjoin(":",,REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\d+)","($1)"))))*24
```

[image]

explanation:

> The formula extracts numeric values (\d+), then join `0:` the `first value` (minutes) `:` and the `second value` (secondes). The result is multiply by 24 to get hours.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, could you explain what it does?

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if it is understandale.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+)h")/24)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+)min")/24/60)+
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+)s")/24/60/60)))
```

[image]